Problem with Deploying NextJS using Vercel
When I use Vercel to deploy my NextJS app, I get some npm network error as follows:
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET

19:52:46.254npm ERR! network aborted

19:52:46.254npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.

19:52:46.254npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.

19:52:46.255npm ERR! network

19:52:46.255npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the

19:52:46.255npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly. See: 'npm help config'

19:52:46.260

19:52:46.260npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /vercel/.npm/\_logs/2024-06-16T11_52_40_188Z-debug-0.log

19:52:46.287Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1

By the way, I am from China
Also, when I try to disconnect my proxy, it doesn't work

have you tried deploy through github?

did you link the github repository

github deploy get the same error.

i  resloved some part of this issue,now another problem came up  npm
npm ERR! FetchError: request to https://mirrors.cloud.tencent.com/npm/zod/-/zod-3.23.8.tgz failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7897
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest. (/node20/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/minipass-fetch/lib/index.js:130:14)
npm ERR!  FetchError: request to https://mirrors.cloud.tencent.com/npm/zod/-/zod-3.23.8.tgz failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7897
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.
